# SwiftData crashes with error: Thread 1: "*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[7]"

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

This is my Model code

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Match {
    var bool: Bool
    var timestamp: Date
    var won: Bool
    var against: String
    var züge: [Zug]
    
    init(bool: Bool, timestamp: Date, won: Bool, against: String, züge: [Zug]) {
        self.bool = bool
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.won = won
        self.against = against
        self.züge = züge
    }
}
```

The error doesn't occur without the züge var, but `Zug` conforms to Codable.

It crashes in `.modelContainer(for: Match.self)`line with that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the *ü* in *züge* which caused the crash. SwiftData (and CoreData?) doesn't support Umlauts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77464479/swiftdata-class-property-naming-issue-with-umlaut-characters It's more "CoreData" that doesn't support the Umlauts.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t find this. Bc I just searched for swiftdata crashes

Comment: It was posted later. It's just that the explaination is in the comments