# SwiftData Class property naming issue with Umlaut characters

Tags: swift, character, swift-data

I've encountered an intriguing issue while working with SwiftData classes involving property names containing Umlaut characters such as Ä, Ü, and Ö. For instance, if I name a property like parameterä, it seems to trigger unexpected crashes in my application with an error message like:

> Thread 1: "*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[xx]".

Here is my example:

```swift
@Model
class Ergebnisse {
    var id: UUID 
    var datum: Date
    var läckergegessen: Bool
    
    init(id: UUID, datum: Date, läckergegessen: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.datum = datum
        self.läckergegessen = läckergegessen
    }
}
```

Upon closer inspection, it appears that using characters with Umlaut marks in property names might be causing the problem. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue? Can you explain the problem for me? I can't understand it and I was so frustrated until I found out the reason for the error message.

Comment: I'd tend to say it's linked to Objective-C limitations. Swift allows more "characters" for naming vars/func, but Objective-C doesn't. And SwiftData is build over CoreData, which is Objective-C (or used to and is still compatible), hence your "Objective-C" error. Prefers using only a-z and 0-9, "_" etc characters, avoid deviating from them for naming variables. I consider bad habit to name var with "strange" characters, as if tomorrow you need to write in another language, don't get used to.

Comment: Offtopic: The proper spelling is *leckergegessen* 

Comment: Yes Objective-C and Core Data, you can't use umlaut characters in entity and attribute names in the Xcode model editor for the Core Data model.